# Excel-VBA How do I stop the FIND method from looping back after the end of my sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a roughly formatted dataset to work with, and I'm using multiple `Find` methods to grab the datapoints I need. My sample database has three periods of data (all on one sheet), with multiple officer names. A name may or may not be in a particular period. I am using the variable `officerSearch` to store the address which serves as the anchor point for the following `Find` method. This works unless an officer name is not in a particular period, then my `Find` methods get off course. More detail in my code comments.

```
For Each k In dateArray.keys  'loops through my periods. Each key is a unique date
For i = 0 To officerListBox.ListCount - 1 
    If officerListBox.Selected(i) = True Then 'Performs _
          Find methods for each officer selected in list box
        officerSearch = Cells.Find(what:=CDate(k), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
           searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Address 'Finds first instance of the first period (k)
        officerSearch = Cells.Find(what:=officerListBox.List(i), _
           after:=Range(officerSearch), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
           searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Address _
       'Finds officer name starting after the date cell was found. _
        But if the raw data set doesn't have the officer name in that period, _
        my Find method will find an officer name further on down the sheet _
        (or loop around at the beginning of the sheet) where the name is found in a different period. 
        officerSearch = Cells.Find(what:="Gross Loans", after:=Range(officerSearch), _
           LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
           searchdirection:=xlNext).Address 'Finds the cell labeled Gross Loans starting after an officer name is found
        officerSearch = Cells.Find(what:="Total 30 - 59 days past due", _ 
           after:=Range(officerSearch), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
           searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Address 'Finds the cell _
        labeled Total 30-59 days past due starting after _
        an officer name is found.

    End If
    Next i 'Starts the find loop over for the next selected officer name
Next k 'Starts the find loop over for the next period in the dataset
```

So my 1st, 3rd, and 4th Find methods are guaranteed to be present in the spot I expect, but the 2nd Find method may not be located in the period my loop is searching for, therefore throwing everything else off. I'm stumped on how to account for this.

Comment: *may not be located in the period my loop is searching for* the scope of the `.Find` method in your code is the `Worksheet.Cells`, i.e., the **entire worksheet**.  You need a better way of defining the search range for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th `Find` calls, because as currently written, the second `.Find` will search from (as you observe) the first instance of your period to the entire worksheet below it.

Comment: Is the data sorted, perhaps by date?

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the results of `.Find` as a `Range` object, and check for `Nothing`-ness, rather than chaining methods/properties (e.g., `.Address`) to an object that may not exist (i.e., the value is not found).

It's probably also a good idea to use different variable names for different things, while you can of course re-cast to `officerSearch`, it's potentially confusing and limiting to do so, and besides, variables are cheap.

Ideally, rather than starting with `Cells.Find`, you want to define a table or range of cells that you're concerned with, and then use that as the basis of `.Find` instead of invoking that method against the entire worksheet. This is the `dataRange` object you need to define.

```
Dim dataRange As Range '## range containing ALL data
Set data Range = Range(...) '## MODIFY AS NEEDED
Dim searchRange as Range, offName as Range, grossLoans as Range, pastDue as Range
'## Finds first instance of the first period (k) in the worksheet.Cells
Set searchRange = dataRange.Find(what:=CDate(k), LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext) 

'## Define the range of cells containing this (k) period:
'    Assumes the (k) date is only present in one column
Set searchRange = searchRange.Resize(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataRange, CDate(k))

'## Finds officer name ONLY WITHIN THE searchRange, defined above
Set offName = searchRange.Find(what:=officerListBox.List(i), after:=Range(officerSearch.Cells(1).Address), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)  

'## Get out of here if the value isn't found
If offName Is Nothing Then
    ' you probably want a GoTo or Exit For statement here...
    MsgBox "Not found!"
Else
    '## Otherwise, find Gross Loans beneath Officer Name:
    Set grossLoans = searchRange.Find(what:="Gross Loans", after:=Range(offName.Address), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext) 
    Set pastDue = searchRange.Find(what:="Total 30 - 59 days past due", after:=Range(grossLoans.Address), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext) 
End If
```

## How it Works:

1. First we define `searchRange` as the initial found range in the `dataRange` with your `CDate(k)` value.
2. Then we `Resize` this based on *how many instances of that date
   value* exist in the `dataRange`.

   - We'll use this resized `searchRange` as the parent of the `.Find` method for ALL subsequent calls, that way we are limiting it to the particular date period (k).
3. Then we find the officer name.

   - If the officer name isn't found, you probably want to do something else, right now there is a placeholder `MsgBox`.
4. If the officer name *is* found, then we find Gross Loans and Past Due ranges, assigning each to a corresponding range variable (`grossLoans`, `pastDue` respectively).

**Note**: Code is untested and may contain typos, misplaced parentheses, etc. In particular the `searchRange.CurrentRegion` is maybe not reliable, and it would be better if you can define the range of cells containing relevant data outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to have worked. I re-did my code with one change from your solution. I was able to do some formatting magic so that each statement period was a single `currentregion`, therefore I didn't need to use `Resize` or `CountA`, but rather `Set SearchRange = SearchRange.CurrentRegion`.

Comment: @GoldStandard that will probably work if you don't have contiguous data i.e., each "set" of data is separated by 1 or more empty rows. If it's a contiguous table of data with no empty rows, then `CurrentRegion` probably won't work :)  Good job tweaking this code to your solution!!